# Can OpenEBS support across AWS regions?

Tags: openebs

Is there a way to use openebs across aws regions if I have a vpn, or vpc peering set up? I have seen that OpenEBS supports across AZs in a region but want to know whether I can take backup across region?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenEBS across zone is supported in AWS. You can go through integration section of openebs docs site.
Tried creating the zone using

```
kops create cluster --name=<cluster_name>.k8s.local --vpc=<vpc_id> --zones=<zone1_name>,<zone2_name>,<zone3_name>
```

Post that regular installation of OpenEBS.